# Swiftでピンクノイズ、ホワイトノイズを作成し再生したい。

Tags: swift, swift2

タイトルの通りですが、
Swiftでピンクノイズとホワイトノイズを作成する方法はありますか？
また、作成した音声をiOSで再生できるでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

> Swiftでピンクノイズとホワイトノイズを作成する方法はありますか？

Appleフレームワーク内に簡単に生成できるものはなかったと思うので、
自作すれば可能だと思います。

> また、作成した音声をiOSで再生できるでしょうか

できます。